# Vue-Router returns "Cannot redefine property: $router" error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

im creating a small site using vue.js, im trying to setup a vue-router(which hasn't worked at all so far). im getting the "Cannot redefine property: $router" error.
here is my code.
App.Vue

```
<div id="app">
<div class="header">
  <div class="tab">
    <router-link to="/page1">page1</router-link>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <router-link to="/page2">page2</router-link>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <router-link to="/page3">page3</router-link>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <router-link to="/page4">page4</router-link>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Page1.vue

```
 <template>
    <div>
        <h3>sup</h3>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    export default {
      name: 'app',
      data () {
        return {
          msg: 'hello world'
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
  <style>

  </style>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
const Page1 = { template: '<div>Page1</div>' }
const Page2 = { template: '<div>Page2</div>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/page1', component: Page1 },
  { path: '/page2', component: Page1 }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>hello-world</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

ive worked with vue-router before and ran into this problem. i feel like im missing something but i dont know what, any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicate your Vue instance.

Check this.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const Page1 = { template: '<div>Page1</div>' }
const Page2 = { template: '<div>Page2</div>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/page1', component: Page1 },
  { path: '/page2', component: Page1 }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your main Vue instantiation is duplicated:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

and:

```
const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

I think this is the source of the problem. I suppose it can look like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const Page1 = { template: '<div>Page1</div>' }
const Page2 = { template: '<div>Page2</div>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/page1', component: Page1 },
  { path: '/page2', component: Page1 }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```